# Height not changing in a div with CSS

Tags: html, css, electron

when i try to change my div's height it doesn't move when i input the height. I want it to touch the top of the window and it isn't here is the code.

**CSS**

```css
.shop {
   position: absolute;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
   min-height:100%;
   left: 1022px; 
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
   padding: 10px; 
   overflow-y:scroll;
   text-align: center;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
 <div class="shop">
   <h1 style="text-align: unset;">Shop</h1>
   <div class="upgrades">
   </div>
   <div class="buildings">
     <button>
       <div class="clicker">
         <h1 class="title">Clicker</h1>
         <h2 id="cost">Cost: 15 Dollar's</h2>
         <p class="description">A nice little clicker kind of look's like a glove...</p>
       </div>
     </button>
     <button>
       <div class="snow">
         <h1 class="title">Snowglobe's</h1>
         <h2 id="cost">Cost: 350 Dollar's</h2>
         <p class="description">Shake it up to get some cash :]</p>
       </div>
     </button>
     <button>
       <div class="farm">
         <h1 class="title">Farm's</h1>
         <h2 id="cost">Cost: 500 Dollar's</h2>
         <p class="description">Farm some food and sell if this might be helpful in the long run....</p>
       </div>
     </button>
     <button>
       <div class="factory">
         <span class="tooltipfac">What is this? Well we got to find out by buying it :]</span>
         <h1 class="title">Factorie's</h1>
         <h2 id="cost">Cost: 5600 Dollar's</h2>
         <p class="description">Hey a factory might help to build stuff to help!</p>
       </div>
     </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I did try the code mentioned above and i was expecting for the div to go to the top of my window. Here is a picture of what i want and what happened.[The highlighted part is where i want the div and the div was also mentioned and is surrounded by a green border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDiUK.png)

*Note: I am using electron to run the window and the code*

Comment: The green border block is `.shop`?

Comment: Height wont move div to top, I think you need `top:0`.

Comment: Yes the green block is ```.shop```

Comment: I'll try ```top:0```

Comment: @Shuo ```top:0``` work's thank's for the help :)

Comment: @shuo Add that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding top: 0 to the shop element should do the trick.
The top property specifies the vertical position of the element

```css
.shop {
   top: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   left: 1022px; 
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
   padding: 10px; 
   overflow-y: scroll;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
}
```